# How to display a list of users with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

When I do this: `<%= f.association :user, :collection =>  User.where(:country_id => 1) %>`

My dropdown is populated with lines like this:
`#<User:0x0000010b98d170>`

Instead, I would like to display an email, that is tied to the id of the users.

I have yet to find how to override the value / content defaults of simple_form when using associations.

Can anyone help?

thank you,
P.

Comment: Please use backticks or four space indenting for code examples in your questions.

Comment: Which version of rails are you using. I'm not familiar with the association method.

Comment: It's a method from the simple_form gem. I'm using rails 3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although the page on github (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) didn't say, but I guess it's the same as the example `f.input :age, :collection => 18..60`

You could use `:label_method` and `:value_method`:

```
f.association :user, :collection => User.where(:country_id => 1), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id
```

I did not use it before. Please tell me if it does not work.