Select form in Rails simple_form returns hexadecimal address of object
Im' testing very simple form in rails using simple_form gem. I have three models as below:
class Raport < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :systemname
  belongs_to :user
end

class Systemname < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :raports
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :raports
end

My new.html.erb file
<%= simple_form_for @raport do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :systemname, prompt: "---choose one---" %>
  <%= f.input :rsi %>
  <%= f.input :crit %>

  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>

<% end %>

My model's stucture
model user user:string email:string
model systemname sname:string
model raport sysname:string rsi:integer crit:string user_id:integer systemname_id:integer

I added to model systemname a few sname entires but my dropdown form presents them as hexadecimal entires like this:

What did I miss this time?

In the Docs: In case you want to declare different labels and values f.association :company, label_method: :company_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false So probably f.association :systemname, label_method: :sname, value_method: :id, prompt: "---choose one---"

Does this answer your question? Rails Form Association Field Shows Object Instead of Name Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810954/how-to-display-a-list-of-users-with-simple-form and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106021/simple-form-association-helper and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037755/simple-form-gem-how-to-display-the-name-of-a-model-in-an-association-rails-4, ...

On a side note it can be good to know that "hexadecimal entries" you're getting is the output from Object#to_s which is the default when any Ruby object is cast into a string.

you can also just define to_label method in your model https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form?tab=readme-ov-file#collections
